# xml excape form a python dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, lambda

I have a list of dictionaries and want to iterate through the keys in order to escape xml characters. I need to find strings containing characters needing xml escaping, update them and add them back into the list of dictionaries.

There are two keys which needs to be checked and updated 'name' and 'name1'.

My list looks like this:

```
list: [{'level1': 3, 'code1': u'7000', 'name1': u'Donations received in the field', 'code': u'6100', 'name': u'Per diem', 'level': 3, 'balance': 0.0, 'balance1': -1986.9100000000001}, {'level1': 3, 'code1': u'7100', 'name1': u'Interest income', 'code': u'6101', 'name': u'Team living Expenses', 'level': 3, 'balance': 0.0, 'balance1': 0.0}, etc ... ]
```

My code so far, but the 'key' variable is returning a integer and the 'val' holds the key... (eg: 'level1') and it never makes it into the reduce lambda.

```
def get_lines(self,data):
    if data['form']['export_format'] == 'xls':
        for row in self.result_temp:
            for key,val in row.items():
                if key == 'name' or key == 'name1':
                    reduce(lambda s,r: s.replace(*r),
                        [('&', '&amp;'),
                        ('<', '&lt;'),
                        ('>', '&gt;'),
                        ("'", '&#39;'),
                        ('"', '&quot;')],
                        self.result_temp[row][val])
    return self.result_temp
```

Comment: You don't need to iterate entire dictionary items. Just iterate `name`, `name1` keys.

Comment: Thanks @falsetru ... could you post an example ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`cgi.escape`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/cgi.html#cgi.escape) if possible (`"`, `'` is not escaped by `cgi.escape`):

```
>>> import cgi
>>> cgi.escape("""<hello "spam" & 'egg'>'""")
'&lt;hello "spam" &amp; \'egg\'&gt;\''
```

And, you don't need to iterate entire dictionary items. Just iterate `name`, `name1`.

```
def get_lines(self,data):
    if data['form']['export_format'] == 'xls':
        for row in self.result_temp:
            for key in ('name', 'name1'):
                if key not in row:
                    continue
                row[key] = cgi.escape(row[key])
    return self.result_temp
```

---

BTW, in the code of the question, the return value of the `reduce` is not put back to the dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [SAX](http://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.sax.utils.html#module-xml.sax.saxutils) tools and see if that suits your needs before rolling your own.

```
from xml.sax.saxutils import escape

escape_string = """<escape "foo" & 'bar'>"""
extra_entities = {"'": "&#39;", '"': "&quot;"}
escape(escape_string, extra_entities)
```